# What collection to use in an multi-threaded observer pattern?

Tags: c#, multithreading, concurrency, observer-pattern

I am currently implementing a Observer design situation.

I have my list of registered observers in my main class.

```
private static volatile List<IObserver> registeredObservers;
```

Each Observer is a network socket, when the socket is connected and all is good, it registers its self with the observable class. If there is an error or the socket simply disconnects it then de-registers / removes its self from the observable.

This all seems to work well and good. I am happy.

but now in my main class I loop through all the registered observers as below:

```
private void SendEventToObservers(ILogItem item)
{
    foreach (var observer in registeredObservers)
    {
        if (observer != null)
        {
            observer.OnMessageRecieveEvent(new ObserverEvent(item));
        }
    }
}
```

This then throws the following error:

```
Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute
```

Now I have read in another SO thread that I need to change the for each to add the .ToList() :

```
foreach (var observer in registeredObservers.ToList())
```

Now this doesn't quite solve my issue, because if an Observer removes its self from the list while it is busy looping though, the .toList() creates an "old" representation of the list?

I was thinking would there not be a better sort of concurrent list which can block when being accessed and when observers are being added and removed?

Or will the current .ToList() Solution work?

Comment: FWIW, I don't think `volatile` is doing what you expect here. The *reference* to the `List<IObserver>` object would volatile here, not the contents of the list itself. Unless you're planning on changing the list itself, but I wouldn't recommend that. You'd probably be better off making it `readonly`...

Comment: Also, worth a read: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997305%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: The comment with the toList() was quite good in my opinion. Surely it creates an "old" representation of the list, but since you delete elements from the list while iterating it you have to use another instance of this collection. So while iterating changes the elements in registeredObservers the actual loop uses a copy of this list which may not change.

Comment: @lc. Making it read only wouldn't help as I don't only read from it? It is constantly added to and removed from. Add I agree on the volatile, I was just trying it. I should actually remove it.

Comment: @Zapnologica On the contrary, it would make the *reference* readonly. Not the collection itself. That is, you couldn't do `registeredObservers = new List<IObserver>()`. It's a different point though.

Comment: @HimBromBeere ok but now what happens when it tries to call the `OnMessageRecieveEvent` on a list item which doesn't actually exist any-more?

Answer (score 3):

Since you've mentioned it is OK to `block when being accessed and when observers are being added and removed` I think synchronizing the threads is the safest choice.

This will be the best solution if you're not running a time-intensive operation. Just `lock` the list and do the operation:

Add:

```
lock (registeredObservers)
    registeredObservers.Add(newObserver);
```

Remove:

```
lock (registeredObservers)
    registeredObservers.Remove(outOfServiceObserver);
```

Iterate:

```
lock (registeredObservers)
    foreach (var observer in registeredObservers)
    {
        if (observer != null)
        {
            observer.OnMessageRecieveEvent(new ObserverEvent(item));
        }
    }
```

UPDATE:

@fourpastmidnight brought up a serious issue with this solution and I think it's better to edit the answer to something safer: iterating over a copy of the list

```
lock (registeredObservers)
    foreach (var observer in registeredObservers.ToArray())
    {
        if (observer != null)
        {
            observer.OnMessageRecieveEvent(new ObserverEvent(item));
        }
    }
```

Comment: @Zapnologica The `lock` will automatically release when reaching the end of the block scope. `lock { ... }` is akin to having a `try...catch...finally` block with a `System.Threading.Monitor.Enter` and `System.Threading.Monitor.Exit` bookend calls.

Comment: @Alireza However, I still don't think this will work. If the list changes while iterating over it, the `Enumerator` becomes invalid.

Comment: You're totally right. I just assumed here that there is nothing added to or removed from the collection outside the locks.

Comment: @Alireza Of course, I could be misunderstanding the OP. Perhaps during enumeration, someone accesses the collection, subsequently modifying it--all on a separate thread. In which case, your solution works beautifully (if locking is OK).

Comment: @Alireza Good update to your answer. And for completeness, your solution is exactly what the `Concurrent*<T>` collections do in `System.Collections.Concurrent`: they take a snapshot of the collection before iterating over it so that other threads can modify the underlying collection. As stated, this may result in "dirty" reads, but at least you're not blocking while iterating and the application remains responsive to other threads.

Comment: @fourpastmidnight And thanks you for participating :)

Answer (score 1):

When using `foreach` loops, which use an enumerator, you are not able to modify the contents of the collection being enumerated over.

So it looks like while you're enumerating over the collection of sockets, a socket becomes disconnected and is removed from the list (or a new socket is opened and added to the list). Since your list is being used in a multi-threaded scenario, this happens while you're enumerating over the list and the exception occurs. The MSDN documentation is quite clear that the standard .NET collections are not thread-safe.

You need to use a thread-safe collection located in the `System.Collections.Concurrent` namespace, such as `System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentBag<T>` or `System.Collections.Concurrent.BlockingCollection<T>` depending on your needs.